# "Drawing" different sized Tic-tac-toe board

Tags: javascript, html, tic-tac-toe

So I'm making a Tic-tac-toe game using JavaScript and HTML as project for school and teacher asked us to make it possible to "draw" different sized board e.g. 3x3 or 4x4.

And here is what I try to do.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", onLoad, false)

function onLoad() {
  var wins = [7, 56, 448, 73, 146, 292, 273, 84];
  var mainDiv = document.getElementById("mainDiv");
  mainDiv.style.background = "#000000";
  mainDiv.style.width = "306px";
  mainDiv.style.height = "306px";
  mainDiv.style.border = "solid";
  mainDiv.style.borderColor = "#79BDEB";
  mainDiv.style.position = "absolute";
  mainDiv.style.left = "10px";
  mainDiv.style.top = "70px";
  //select.addEventListener("change", onChange, false);
}

function onChange() {
  var select = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
  var main = document.getElementById("mainDiv");
  if (select == 3) {
    three();
  } else if (select == 4) {
    four();
  } else if (select == 5) {
    five();
  } else {
    six();
  }
  main.innerHTML = "";
  counter = 0;
}

function three() {
  var main = document.getElementById("mainDiv");
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      var small = document.createElement("div");
      main.appendChild(small);
      small.style.background = "#52498F";
      small.style.width = "100px";
      small.style.height = "100px";
      small.style.border = "solid";
      small.style.borderColor = "#000000";
      small.style.position = "absolute";
      small.style.left = j * 100 + "px";
      small.style.top = i * 100 + "px";
      small.addEventListener("mousedown", onDown, false);
    }
  }
  var state = false;

  function onDown(e) {
    var small = e.target;
    small.style.background = "#f0f0f0";
    small.style.fontSize = "72px";
    small.style.fontFamily = "Arial";
    if (!state) {
      small.innerHTML = "x";
    } else {
      small.innerHTML = "o";
    }
    state = !state;
    small.style.textAlign = "center";
  }
}

function four() {
  var main = document.getElementById("mainDiv");
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      var small = document.createElement("div");
      main.appendChild(small);
      small.style.background = "#52498F";
      small.style.width = "75px";
      small.style.height = "75px";
      small.style.border = "solid";
      small.style.borderColor = "#000000";
      small.style.position = "absolute";
      small.style.left = j * 75 + "px";
      small.style.top = i * 75 + "px";
      small.addEventListener("mousedown", onDown, false);
    }
  }
  var state = false;

  function onDown(e) {
    var small = e.target;
    small.style.background = "#f0f0f0";
    small.style.fontSize = "60px";
    small.style.fontFamily = "Arial";
    if (!state) {
      small.innerHTML = "x";
    } else {
      small.innerHTML = "o";
    }
    state = !state;
    small.style.textAlign = "center";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Tic-tac-toe</title>
  <script src="logic.js"></script>
  <style>
    #mySelect {
      font-size: 24px;
    }
    #myColor {
      font-size: 24px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <select id="mySelect" onchange="onChange()">
    <option value="3">3 x 3</option>
    <option value="4">4 x 4</option>
    <option value="5">5 x 5</option>
    <option value="6">6 x 6</option>
  </select>
  <select id="myColor" onchange="color()">
    <option value="11">Blue</option>
    <option value="12">Green</option>
    <option value="13">Red</option>
  </select>
  <div id="mainDiv"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

And my problem is that small div's don't draw in the mainDiv. Strange thing is that on PC of one of my friends it works perfectly. But for me and couple of other friends it doesn't.

Comment: How many onDown's do you have?

Comment: Four. I know I could use only one. And now I'm changing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And my problem is that small div's don't draw in the mainDiv

it's cause you're **first** drawing your elements applying the desired fn loop, but **afterwards** you're clearing the whole `#mainDiv` using  `main.innerHTML = "";`

Also, instead of creating different functions like `three()`, `four()`, `five()`...
you can simply **create a single one** `oneField(i, j, n)` and pass to that function the number of iterations you need to apply like:

```
select.addEventListener("change", createMap, false);

function createMap() {
  main.innerHTML = ""; // Clear first, not afterwards!
  var n = this.value;  // 3, 4, 5, ...
  for(var i=0; i<n; i++)  for(var j=0; j<n; j++)  oneField(i, j, n);
  counter = 0;
  turn = 0;
}
```

where `n` can be used to set the field cell width using simple math `fieldWidth = 300 / n`

Regarding your **HTML and Styles**, I would go creating a **Table** element and TR with TD cells instead of DIV, but I don't know your assignment's details. Also Instead of creating styles all over again for every element, I'd simply create a `style` rule like:

```
#mainDIv > div {
    /* Cell styles here */
}
```

In any case here's an example using DIV as you do:

```js
function el(id){ return document.getElementById(id); }

function css(el, prop, val){
  if (typeof prop==="object") {
    for(var key in prop) el.style[key] = prop[key];
  } else {
    el.style[prop] = val;
  }
}

var wins    = [7, 56, 448, 73, 146, 292, 273, 84],
    size    = 300,
    turn    = 0, // 0=O, 1=X
    counter = 0,
    select  = el("mySelect"),
    color   = el("myColor"),
    main    = el("mainDiv");

css(main, {
      background : "#000",
      width      : size+"px",
      height     : size+"px",
      border     : "3px solid #79BDEB",
      position   : "absolute",
      left       : "10px",
      top        : "70px"
    });

select.addEventListener("change", createMap, false);

function oneField(i, j, n){
  var field = document.createElement("div"),
      w = size / n;
  css(field, {
      background : "#52498F",
      width      : w-2 +"px", // -2 is to account 1px border
      height     : w-2 +"px",
      border     : "1px solid #000",
      position   : "absolute",
      left       : j*w +"px",
      top        : i*w +"px",
      fontSize   : w-20 +"px",
      lineHeight : w-15 +"px",
      textAlign  : "center" 
  });
  main.appendChild(field);
  field.addEventListener("mousedown", onDown, false);
  //return field; // Return the created square field HTMLElement
}

function createMap() {
  main.innerHTML = "";
  var n = this.value;
  for(var i=0; i<n; i++)  for(var j=0; j<n; j++)  oneField(i, j, n);
  counter = 0;
  turn = 0;
}

function onDown(e) {
  var targ = e.target;
  css(targ, {
    background : "#f0f0f0" 
  });

  turn ^= 1; // Toggle turn 1,0,1,0...
  targ.innerHTML = turn ? "x" : "o" ;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  font: 16px/1 Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #444;
}
#mySelect,
#myColor {
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="3">3 x 3</option>
  <option value="4">4 x 4</option>
  <option value="5">5 x 5</option>
  <option value="6">6 x 6</option>
</select>

<div id="mainDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Wow! Big thanks this helped me a lot. Im  creating div's because we started doing it that way on lesson. I'll fiddle around and maybe try option with creating table.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using a `div` for your design, why don't you use a table? It's much simpler :)

here's the **jquery**:

```
$("select").change(function(){
  var table = $("table").html("");
  var tr="";
  var size = $(this).val().charAt(0);
  for(var i=1; i<=size; i++){
    for(var j=1; j<=size; j++)
      tr+="<td></td>";
    $(table).append("<tr>"+tr+"</tr>");
    tr="";
  }
});
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/cekumutahipu/1/edit)</kbd>

Comment: Interesting, why `.charAt(0)` ?

Comment: since the options are in the form of 'N x N' (in <select> tag, didn't use the 'value' attribute for <option> tags), I just need the first character 'N' to get the size of the table required.

Comment: ohh I see now. Didn't noticed you removed the `value` attr. P.S: hopefully there won't be an 10x10 table ;)

Comment: also here on SO there's a trend of downvoting (I do that too btw) answers using jQuery on questions that are clearly using Javascript and are tagged as Javascript so... your answer is not that useful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62069/discussion-between-thescorpion-and-roko-c-buljan).

Comment: Well thanks for idea. For now I will stay with only Javascript, but it's good to know how to make it work using jQuery.